# Visual Basic 2010 - Display multiple MySql queries to different datagridviews on a Form

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Good day,

I'm developing a project where I use Visual Basic 2010 and MySql.  The function of the project is to perform sports timing services.  I'm semi-knowledgeable with programming in the above environments, and when I struggle, I Google for answers and it serves me well 99% of the time.

My problem is this: I have a database with tables for each sports event. All the data gets captured and all the functionality is working as intended.  I would now like to display the results of this race on a Form using four GridViews (4 is the most race distances that are allowed).  These results need to be separately displayed (using different queries) for each race distance (4 at most).

I have code to display the results, but this populates all four gridviews with the same data. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub ListResults()

    Dim query As String = "SELECT RaceNo, FirstName, LastName, RaceDistance, RaceTime FROM " & frmMain.EventCode & _
            " WHERE NOT ISNULL(RaceTime) AND RaceDistance = '" & frmMain.RaceDistance1 & "' ORDER BY RaceDistance ASC, RaceTime ASC;"

    Dim connection As New MySqlConnection(frmMain.connStr)
    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(query, connection)
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    Try
        If da.Fill(ds) Then
            dgvLoadResultsA.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            dgvLoadResultsB.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            dgvLoadResultsC.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            dgvLoadResultsD.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    Finally

        da = Nothing
        connection.Close()
        connection = Nothing
    End Try
End Sub
```

I understand that I need to produce four different queries (which I'm able to do), but I'm not sure how to send the results of those queries to the different gridviews. I don't seem to fully understand how to send the result of my queries to different tables in the dataset. I can just create the code by running the sub with different parameters and variables, but thought that there is a better way of doing this.

Any assistance in this matter would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use a different DataSet per Query.

Personally I'd split your Query code into a separate Function taking the Event and Distance as Parameters and returning your DataTable;

```
Private Function GetResults(ByVal EventCode As Integer, ByVal RaceDistance As Integer) As DataTable

    Dim query As String = "SELECT RaceNo, FirstName, LastName, 
                           RaceDistance, RaceTime 
                           FROM " & EventCode & _
                         " WHERE NOT ISNULL(RaceTime) 
                           AND RaceDistance = '" & RaceDistance & "' 
                           ORDER BY RaceDistance ASC, RaceTime ASC;"

    Dim connection As New MySqlConnection(frmMain.connStr)
    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(query, connection)
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    Try
        If da.Fill(ds) Then
            Return ds.Tables(0)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    Finally

        da = Nothing
        connection.Close()
        connection = Nothing
    End Try
End Sub
```

I've assumed your Data Types here, you will of course need to modify this to use the correct Data Types.

Then you can attach your DataSources using;

```
dgvLoadResultsA.DataSource = GetResults(EventCodeA, RaceDistanceA)
dgvLoadResultsB.DataSource = GetResults(EventCodeB, RaceDistanceB)
dgvLoadResultsC.DataSource = GetResults(EventCodeC, RaceDistanceC)
dgvLoadResultsD.DataSource = GetResults(EventCodeD, RaceDistanceD)
```

Ideally you'd also pass in your Connection String to the GetResults Function, then your Function is Unit Testable, but I'll leave that decision to you.

Of course, you should ideally check that your Function returns a valid DataTable before attaching. But I didn't want to over complicate the solution!